# How to get time duration of a video clip

Tags: .net, vb.net, video

Please tell me how can i get time duration of ".wmv" video file (it would be gr8 if it could work for all other also) file using vb.net

i am using vs2008

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may not be a precise answer to your question but it might tell you the concept of reading file attributes, good luck.

http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/advanced-filefolder-properties-viewer/